# How to Handle web based pop up in selenium webdriver using python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to learning selenium. I'm just trying to automate a site as a practice. I'm trying [www.quikr.com](http://www.quikr.com). After the webpage loads it gives a web based pop up i want to select a city in that pop up. I'm unable to select using search by text, ID, xpath.

```
<a class="cs" index="Ahmedabad" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clickcity(this,'bigmodal','ipcity','2','22');">Ahmedabad</a>
```

On click function is hanadled by this javascript function.

What i want to achieve is how to click one of these links in python using webdriver.

Comment: Use this xpath: //a[contains(text(),'Ahmedabad')].

Answer (score 0):

This example selects 'Ahmedabad'

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.quikr.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctystlist']/div[1]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/a")
driver.close()
```

Happy testing!

Answer (score 0):

use below code to select chennai option,

FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

```
    driver.get("http://www.quikr.com/");

    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 180);
    try {
        wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                // driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Chennai')]"));
                if (element.isDisplayed()) {
                    return element;
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception while waiting for " + By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Chennai')]")
                + ". Exception:" + e + " on " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
    }


    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Chennai')]")).click();

    driver.close();
```